# Excel Optimize Stock level with Production and Orders

Tags: excel

I have a big excel file that I use to plan production and deliveries of several different products to customers. Currently I'm doing the planning of production manually which is starting to get very time consuming since the amount of products are increasing. So I've been trying to make some steps of the process automatic instead but I'm currently stuck on one issue.

I've created simplified version of the excel file to show as an example in the picture below. What I would like to do is to be able to set a target stock level for Part A and based on that target stock level have the file calculate how many parts needs to be produced. However this causes a circular calculation since the production will affect the stock level.I've tried with iterative calculations to solve it but I get really big deviations compared to the target stock level that I have set.

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to achieve this or do I need to create a Macro for this instead?

Comment: please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Should production cause a circular reference? Stock on 18th is 0, production on 18th -> 1000 -> stock on 19th 1000 -> production on 19th = 0. If it's more complicated, maybe look at [solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040).